# '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object' cause crash

Tags: swift

I am assigning UserInfo Dictionary from NSUserDefault as NSMutableDictionary.
Now my dicInfo is mutable dictionary, but object it contains are immutable.
So, when i am trying to replace those value it cause crash.
I am attaching image which describe crash report.
If any solution, to how to convert inner object of mutable dictionary to mutable.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Post your code, not a screenshot of your code.  Post your exception, not a screenshot of your exception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `NSDictionary` class conforms to the `NSMutableCopying` protocol.  As such, we can call the `mutableCopy` method on an `NSDictionary` to get an `NSMutableDictionary` copy of the object.

```
let dicInfo = userSharedDefaults?.objectForKey(UserDefaultKey.kUserBasicInfo) as? NSDictionary

let mutableDictionary = dicInfo?.mutableCopy
```

In Swift, we may need to cast this as the correct type:

```
let mutableDictionary = dicInfo?.mutableCopy as? NSMutableDictionary
```

Comment: That works thanks, but do you have any idea how to save that NSDictionary back to plist file? I got an low level error in Xcode 10, Swift 4.1 using write(to: URL) func. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var dicInfo = (userSharedDefault.object(forKey: "kUserbasicInfo") as! NSDictionary).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create Mutable Dictionary as follows:
It will fix the crash.

```
let dicInfo = NSMutableDictionary.init(dictionary: userSharedDefaults?.objectForKey(UserDefaultKey.kUserBasicInfo) as! NSDictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither use `NSMutableDictionary` nor `mutableCopy()` in Swift to get a mutable dictionary from `UserDefaults`.

## **Never do that**.

Normally far be it from me to criticize other answers but `NSMutableDictionary` and `mutableCopy()` are indeed inappropriate API in Swift.

---

- To get a dictionary from `UserDefaults` use dedicated method `dictionary(forKey:`. The default dictionary type is `[String:Any]`
- To make an object mutable simply use the `var` keyword

  ```
  var userbasicInfo : [String:Any]
  if let dictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: UserDefaultKey.kUserBasicInfo) {
      userbasicInfo = dictionary
  } else {
      userbasicInfo = [String:Any]()
  }
  userbasicInfo[kPin] = 5678
  print(userbasicInfo)
  UserDefaults.standard.set(userbasicInfo, forKey:UserDefaultKey.kUserBasicInfo)
  ```